# Get commit history after date (since/after parameter)

Tags: git, shell, date, version-control

It`s 8 of March now. I want to see git history since 1 of March. For that I'm using command:

```
$ git log --pretty="%cd - %h - %an - %s" --after="2013-3-01 0am"
```

It works fine. Then I want to see history "in future" (since 8 of March increase `after` value by +1 day). Example:

```
$ git log --pretty="%cd - %h - %an - %s" --after="2013-3-11 0am"
```

Command returns empty history, which is correct. Then `after` value equals to 18:

```
$ git log --pretty="%cd - %h - %an - %s" --after="2013-3-18 0am"
```

Git starts to return **full month history**. Why? Seems like something wrong with `git log` date time format in my example.

git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd commands are identical. Also, you said increase `after` by +1 but you set it to after the 11th, not the 8th.

Comment: Fixed. 11 - is one of value in 8-17 range.

Comment: I seem to remember something going into `git` to interpret the ambiguous date `2013-3-11` differently based on the separator character (is that March 11, or November 3? Europeans and Americans differ on that). Try it with `/` or a `.` as a separator instead and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open bug](https://git-scm.atlassian.net/browse/AUTO-3072) on this issue. If you've built git from source, a `test-date` utility is included. Here are some results of running various dates through it (note - 18th is no longer the break point for me, so using the 19th):

```
$ ./test-date approxidate "2013-3-01 0am"
2013-3-01 0am -> 2013-03-01 19:22:21 +0000

$ ./test-date approxidate "2013-3-11 0am"
2013-3-11 0am -> 2013-03-11 19:22:21 +0000

$ ./test-date approxidate "2013-3-19 0am"
2013-3-19 0am -> 2013-03-03 19:22:21 +0000
```

It's clear the time is problematic in all cases, so lets fix the time:

```
$ ./test-date approxidate "2013-3-01 0:00"
2013-3-01 0:00 -> 2013-03-01 08:00:00 +0000
$ ./test-date approxidate "2013-3-19 0:00"
2013-3-19 0:00 -> 2013-03-19 07:00:00 +0000
```

That looks a little better, and our future date is no longer seriously incorrect, but the times are relative to my timezone, and differ between being with and without DST (E: for any future readers, the DST shift occurred 2013-03-10, so those dates do encompass the shift).

```
$ ./test-date approxidate "2013-3-19 0:00 +0000"
2013-3-19 0:00 +0000 -> 2013-03-19 00:00:00 +0000
```

Now our date is looking a little better. If I do want the timezone to take affect, it's now easy to change to a `-0800`/`-0700`, `PST`, `PDT`, or any other timezone.

In short, there are two issues:

1. Your time is not being parsed properly. Once a time component is included, git gets smarter about parsing dates.
2. In a quest to parse any date, git discards your `dd` and uses your `mm` for a day of the current month:

   ```
   $ ./test-date approxidate "2013-3-20"
   2013-3-20 -> 2013-03-03 19:22:21 +0000
   $ ./test-date approxidate "2013-4-19"
   2013-4-19 -> 2013-03-04 19:22:21 +0000
   $ ./test-date approxidate "2013-4-32"
   2013-4-32 -> 2013-03-04 19:22:21 +0000
   ```

Your issue should be fixable by fixing the time and optionally adding a time zone depending on intent.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer. After I read it I replaced date template to `"%d.%m.%Y"` and it worked.